# Share color and labels on subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, label

I'm trying to create subplots that share the same color and label for the same points. I have a small example down below.
Each point has a label as an integer, and a direction string that I use for labeling and also filtering. For showing the correct label without creating a single scatter for each, I use the (handle, label) option in the legend. (In my data there are more than 3 directions)

My problem is that the code below shows the wrong label for the filtered data, and also another color. How can I

- Get the same color and
- the same label for each filtered point as in the first plot?

I get that matplotlib gives a list of different handles, and if there are only 2, the first 2 entries of the direction list are used. I just don't know if there's a way to use the label ints to get the correct direction.
Plot of the code below:
[image]

PS: This is my first question here so sorry if there are some mistakes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.arange(0, 12)
Y = X
labels = np.array([x % 3 for x in X])
directions = ['left', 'right', 'up']*4

right_only = np.array([True if direc in ['right', 'up'] else False for direc in directions])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, sharey='all', sharex='all')

scatter = ax1.scatter(X, Y, c=labels)
ax1.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=directions)

scatter2 = ax2.scatter(X[right_only], Y[right_only], c=labels[right_only])
ax2.legend(handles=scatter2.legend_elements()[0], labels=directions)
```

Comment: You can add `vmin=0, vmax=2` to both calls to `scatter()`.  That way 0, 1 and 2 will always be mapped to the same color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct the color of the scatter points on the right plot to be in line with the left plot, you could use "vmin=..., vmax=..." and set them to the minimum and maximum values on your labels array. That would keep the cmap range to be constant between them.

For the same labels between plots, you need to remove the indices that are not part of "right_only". What worked for me was to use "np.delete(directions, ~right_only)", which removes the False indices of "right_only" from the "directions" list.

Here's what I did:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.arange(0, 12)
Y = X
labels = np.array([x % 3 for x in X])
directions = ['left', 'right', 'up']*4

right_only = np.array([True if direc in ['right', 'up'] else False for direc in directions])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, sharey='all', sharex='all')

scatter = ax1.scatter(X, Y, c=labels)
ax1.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=directions)

scatter2 = ax2.scatter(X[right_only], Y[right_only], c=labels[right_only], vmin=np.min(labels), vmax=np.max(labels))
ax2.legend(handles=scatter2.legend_elements()[0], labels=list(np.delete(directions, ~right_only)))
```

[image: Plot of the above code]

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted! Didn't knew about vmin and vmax.

Comment: On a side note, I had to adapt the solution for my other code a bit. If you happen to have only an array of unique directions instead of a direction for every value, this works:
`labels=list(np.delete(directions, ~np.unique(labels[right_only])))`
Maybe this will help someone who stumbles across the same problem.